# Why are Golang TLS Cipher Suites not showing up in nmap?

Tags: go, tls1.2, nmap

I've created a web server in Golang 1.19 and configured the minimum TLS version to 1.2, with a restricted set of Cipher suites:

```
config := &tls.Config{
    Certificates: certs,
    MinVersion:   tls.VersionTLS12,
    CipherSuites: []uint16{
        tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
        tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
        tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
        tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
    },
}
```

I then deployed my web server to a Linux server and ran nmap. The results were unexpected:

```
> nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 myserver.mydomain.com

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2023-07-31 07:24 PDT
Nmap scan report for myserver.mydomain.com (<IP redacted>)
Host is up (0.00052s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 - strong
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|_  least strength: strong

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
```

What happened to the `ECDHE` cipher suites? Why aren't they showing up in nmap?

Answer (score 3):

Go up to version 1.20 did not support ECDHE ciphers if the client was missing the `ec_point_formats` TLS extension in the ClientHello. Since the nmap script does not send this extension the ECDHE ciphers are not working when the code is compiled with older versions of Go. With a recent version (tried 1.20.6) the issue is fixed, i.e. all the ciphers are detected.

For more see [crypto/tls: support ECDHE key exchanges when ec_point_formats is missing in ClientHello extension #49126](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/49126).